# If no blog entries, show something else

Tags: entries, filter

I'm having a bit of trouble showing a message if there's no entries in my blog. I tried the length filter but my empty message wont show:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('volunteerPosition').find() %}
  {% if entry.volunteerPosition|length %}

      {{entry.volunteerShortDescription}}

  {% else %}

      Sorry, Nothing to show.

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
{# Get all of the entries in the 'volunteerPosition' section #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('volunteerPosition').find() %}

{# Do we have any %}
{% if entries|length %}

    {# Loop through them #}
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>{{ entry.volunteerShortDescription }}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% else %}
    {# Nothing to see here #}
    Sorry, nothing to show.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yep that did it! I just had to change that endif to an endfor for the looping content. Thanks a bunch!